# Is there a way to put find_element_by_xpath inside for loop?

Tags: python, selenium, for-loop

I am using python with selenium to try to iterate over a loop.

Here is my code:

```
rowsArray = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("search-results__result-item")
countRows = (len(rowsArray))
```

This way I fint countRows = 25 and then I try to iterate in a for loop:

```
for i in range(countRows):
   row = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("search-results__result-item")[i]
   print(row)
```

This way it works well, but since I need to get elements inside the element that has the 'search-results__result-item' class, I tried to change it using xpath inside the loop:

```
row = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//li[contains(@class, 'search-results__result-item')][" + str(i) + "]"
```

or

```
row = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//li[@class='search-results__result-item']" + str(i) + "]")
```

But all I get is the message:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: //li[@class='search-results__result-item'][0]
```

What is the right way to iterate over a loop using XPath?

Comment: Can you share the link to page you are working on and more your code? It's not clear enough what elements are you trying to access inside what elements etc.

Comment: I can (https://www.linkedin.com/sales/search/saved-searches/company), but its inside sales navigator so I dont think you are going to have access.

Comment: The fact is that the items exist since I can find them using find_elements_by_class_name. Whats the right way to do the same loop using xpath?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//li[@class='search-results__result-item'][0]
```

the clue is here `[0]` does not represent any node it should start from `[1]`

or use the below code:

```
j = 1
for i in range(len(driver.find_elements_by_class_name("search-results__result-item"))):
    row = driver.find_element_by_xpath(f"(.//li[contains(@class, 'search-results__result-item')])[{j}]")
    print(row.text)
    j = j + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem correctly, then yes it is possible.if you need to access child element under the same parent each time you can use the following two options.

Option 1:

```
rowsArray = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("search-results__result-item")
countRows = (len(rowsArray))

for i in range(countRows):
    childelement=rowsArray[i].find_element_by_xpath(".//li[contains(@class, 'search-results__result-item')]")
```

Option 2:

```
rowsArray = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("search-results__result-item")

for row in rowsArray:
   childelement=row.find_element_by_xpath(".//li[contains(@class, 'search-results__result-item')]")
```

Comment: Same error:
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: .//li[contains(@class, 'search-results__result-item')]

I want to access item with index "i" each time I iterate in loop

Comment: @HugoAroeira : Please provide some delay using explicit wait or `time.sleep(5)` and let me know how this goes?

Comment: @HugoAroeira : Can you add the relevant HTML in your original post?